# Rockwool or Fiberglass Insulation for Basement

Tags: insulation

My current basement is unfinished and would like to finish it. I’m framing an inch or two off the cinder block. I would like to use to Rockwool for better sound protection and just in case there is moisture. I have French drains with plastic dimples coming up 6“ from below the floor just in case there is any moisture from the wall. I would like to keep the Rockwool and inch off the cinder block so it doesn’t absorb moisture.

I was considering faced Fiberglass so I can staple it to the studs and keep it off the cinder block. Is there a trick to keep the rock wool from settling on the cinder block? I guess I can install thin strips of wood behind the 2x4 to hold it in place but thinking there must be a better way. Thanks so much.

Comment: what's your climate zone?

Comment: You can get faced rockwool batting, I believe. Though the stuff iny house is held in place by spring wires between the joists rather than by facing and staples.

Comment: Generally speaking, whether in batts or rolls, insulation will be a bit of a friction fit between the studs. You should just be able to squeeze it into place and have it stay there. Once it's in contact with the block on the back, studs on the sides, and drywall on the front, there should be plenty of friction to keep it from creeping down the wall.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the net that's typically used to contain blown cellulose on the back of your framing to maintain space to the block wall.

**blown cellulose insulation netting** will find the stuff.